# Magento multicountry set-up (1 domain, or more domains, or /countryname subdir)

Tags: multistore, seo, stores

when setting up a new store view I was wondering what the best of the best method is to set-up multistores - in multicountries.

For store A we have

- storeA.com => English
- winkel1.com => Dutch
- geschafte1.com => German

For store B this trick does not work, we only have 1 domain

- StoreB.com => English, Dutch and German

Now what is the best SEO friendly way to set-up these Dutch and German stores?

1. Do I create a store view with subdirectory /nl and /de
2. Or maybe with subdomain nl.StoreB.com and de.StoreB.com
3. Or would I use the same main store URL (and install some GEO ip); but how then does the sitemaps work?

I can imagine that method 3 looks easier to start. You already start the domain with autority, but the language/goal country gest confused. With method 1 you loose all existing SEO and start again, but focussed on a country.

Many thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1):

With method 1 you can keep the SEO for the main domain (as long as the main website website was and will remain the same)

Method 2 would work but again you would need to start SEO on Dutch and German.

Method 3 would probably not work very well, because of using the same base urls.In addition I wonder how you would do any page caching (if required) as one url would give different output for different locations.